# Dynamic recursive foreach and if statement to output sub menu

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, recursion

Below picture of "Menu" shows the menu that I want to design and picture of "table: menu" shows a table with records that are used to develop the Menu. The most bottom is my view of code that applies **`HTML`** and **`PHP`** together. Up to now I have 2 levels of sub menu as shown in Menu, how if I want to have more levels of sub menu which depends on the table records? Instead of hard code it, I want to have dynamic recursive foreach and if statements. How many times of recursive will depend on the table records? How could I done it? Currently I am using Code igniter. Thanks

**Menu**

[image: Menu]

**table: menu**

[image]

```
<ul class="sidebar-menu">

 <?php 
 $main = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM menu WHERE link_id = '' ");
 foreach($main->result() as $row)
 { 
   $check_main = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM menu WHERE link_id IN (SELECT id FROM menu WHERE id = '$row->id')  ");

   if($check_main->num_rows() > 0) 
   { ?>

  <li class="treeview">
    <a href="#">
      <i class="fa fa-share"></i> <span><?php echo $row->description; ?></span>
      <span class="pull-right-container">
        <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
      </span>
    </a>
    <ul class="treeview-menu">

      <?php
      $main2 = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM menu WHERE link_id = '$row->id' ");

      foreach($main2->result() as $row2)
      { 
        $check_main2 = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM menu WHERE link_id = '$row2->id'  ");

        if($check_main2->num_rows() > 0)
        { ?>

          <li>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i><?php echo $row2->description; ?>
              <span class="pull-right-container">
                <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
              </span>
            </a>
            <ul class="treeview-menu">

              <?php
              $main3 = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM menu WHERE link_id = '$row2->id' ");

              foreach($main3->result() as $row3)
              { 
                $check_main3 = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM menu WHERE link_id = '$row3->id'  ");

                if($check_main3->num_rows() > 0)
                { ?>

                  <li>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i><?php echo $row3->description; ?>
                      <span class="pull-right-container">
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                      </span>
                    </a>
                  </li>

                <?php } 
                else
                { ?>

                  <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('Report_controller'); ?>?guid=<?php echo $row3->id; ?>"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i><?php echo $row3->description; ?></a></li>

                <?php } 
              } ?>

            </ul>
          </li>

        <?php }
        else
        { ?>

          <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('Report_controller'); ?>?guid=<?php echo $row2->id; ?>"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i><?php echo $row2->description; ?></a></li>

        <?php } 
      } ?>

    </ul>
  </li>

<?php }
else
{ ?>

  <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('Report_controller'); ?>?guid=<?php echo $row->id; ?>"><i class="fa fa-share"></i><?php echo $row->description; ?></a></li>

<?php } 
} ?>

</ul>
```

Comment: If you factor out the code which generates a menu into a function (your main `foreach` loop) and then during that function you can decide if you need to call the function again for a submenu (hence the recursion)

Comment: Could you provide me an example of doing it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is your structure, you've to separate DB Queries into an own model, please read the [Codeigniter Overview Section](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/index.html) carefully especially the part about [MVC](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/mvc.html)

Based on your code i think i can guide you in the right direction

Create a `Menu_model` called Menu_model.php

```
class Menu_Model extends Base_Model
{
    public function getTreeItems()
    {
        $query = $this->db
            ->select('*')
            ->from('menu')
            ->get();

        $arrTree = $query->result();
        $arrTreeById = [];
        $arrItems = [];

        foreach($arrTree AS $objItem)
        {
            $arrTreeById[$objItem->id] = $objItem;
            $objItem->arrChilds = [];
        }

        foreach($arrTreeById AS $objItem)
        {
            if ($objItem->link_id == 0) $arrItems[] = $objItem;
            if (isset($arrTreeById[$objItem->link_id])) $arrTreeById[$objItem->link_id]->arrChilds[] =  $objItem;
        }

        return $arrItems;
    }
}
```

In your controller function you simply load this model e.g.

```
public function tree()
{
    $this->load->model('menu_model');
    $arrData = $this->Menu_Model->getTreeItems();
    $this->load->view('menu', ['arrData' => $arrData]);
}
```

and now in your view e.g. menu.php

```
function createTree($arrData, $level = 0)
{
    if (count($arrData) > 0)
    {
        if ($level == 0)
        {
            $strUlClass ='sidebar-menu';
            $strCSSFaClass = 'fa-share';
        }
        else
        {
            $strUlClass ='treeview-menu';
            $strCSSFaClass = 'fa-circle-o';
        }
        echo '<ul class="'.$strUlClass.'">';
        foreacH($arrData AS $objItem)
        {
            echo '<li class="treeview"><a href="#"><i class="fa '.$strCSSFaClass.'"></i><span>'.$objItem->description.'</span></a>';
            if (isset($objItem->arrChilds) && count($objItem->arrChilds) > 0)
            {
                createTree($objItem->arrChilds,$level+1);
            }
            echo '</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';

    }
}
createTree($arrData);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, i still can't get the right solution.

Comment: it should work - i tested it and it worked perfectly - what's your problem ?

Comment: I realized that "function createTree($arrData, $level = 0)" cannot be read in my view. Why?

Comment: did you put this function in your view too ?

Comment: Yes. I did exactly what you taught me.

Comment: whats your error ? pls post the exact error information - or did you forget the starting php tag `<?php` in your view ?